# Hyphenations in bibtex

Tags: latex, bibtex, babeljs

Good morning/afternoon/evening.

I want to get automatic hyphenation placement in a BibTeX (with babel). My google-fu skill isn't enough to find solution. Everything that i found is manual hyphenation placement through `{\-}` (like `title = "{Wi\-ki\-pe\-dia}"`).

Is it possible to use babel with BibTeX? How to enable it? I'm interested for hyphenations of english and russian words, if it needs for finding solution.

UPD:

My problems was in "gost71u" bibtex style. I found style "unsrt" that looks like "gost71u" but it can place hyphenations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I seem to have found a solution over [here](http://www.latex-community.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=50&t=3584).

Comment: Well, i found solution by this link. I had no hyphenations because i was using gost71u style. I changed it to "plain" and hyphenations appeared.